# What is the difference between normal function call and signal() system call?

Tags: c, unix, signals

While learning signal() system call, I supposed to come across the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
void sigproc(int);
void quitproc(int);

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
 signal(SIGINT, sigproc); //Is it like a normal Call to signal()?
 signal(SIGQUIT, quitproc);// This too?
 printf("ctrl- c disabled use ctrl\ to quit \n");
 while(1);
 return 0;
}

void sigproc(int signo)
{
printf("you have pressed ctrl - c \n");
}

void quitproc(int signo)
{
  printf("U cant quit\n");
//  exit(0);
}
```

I am calling the function signal() twice in main(). But its executed only when I'm pressing Ctrl-C and Ctrl-\ keys. I thought its also like normal function call. What is actually happening in the signal handler functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `signal` function establishes a signal handler. What it means: "*When my process receives this signal, run this function instead of doing whatever the default was*".

So, in your example the calls to `signal` **don't call the function**. To actually see the signals in action, do this:

- Start your process in one terminal
- From another terminal:

  ```
  kill -INT `pidof proc`
  ```

As a side note, `printf` and friends aren't async-signal-safe. It might come as a shocker, but **it's unsafe to use them in signal handlers**.

---

As a side side note, even if you tagged your question `Unix` it's important to know that signals (and the `signal` function) are standard, integral parts of C. Signal handling and the `signal` function are described in C99 in §7.14.1.